# -Djava.library.path woes

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, classloader

My Java app uses JNI to access some C++ native code. I need in particular this library ***symbolic_graph_jni*** (written by me), which needs glog (from google). I confirmed that libsymbolic_graph_jni.so depends on libglog.so.0. Here is the structure of the dependencies in ldd:

```
|1276|lib>ldd libsymbolic_graph_jni.so 
.... 
libcommon.so => not found
libstorage.so => not found
libdatabase.so => not found
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9d5ff000)
libglog.so.0 => not found
....
```

in my Java app, although I set:

```
-Djava.library.path=~/myproduct/build/impl/libs
```

and that directory contains:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mldv eng    18389 Aug  9 08:54 libboost_system.so.1.58.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mldv eng  3141033 Aug  9 08:54 libcommon.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mldv eng 47034505 Aug  9 08:54 libdatabase.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 mldv eng   528031 Aug  9 08:54 libgcc_s.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mldv eng  1451910 Aug  9 08:54 libgflags.so.2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mldv eng   873073 Aug  9 08:54 libglog.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mldv eng  6520243 Aug  9 08:54 libstdc++.so.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mldv eng  8060525 Aug  9 08:54 libstorage.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mldv eng  1818771 Aug  9 08:54 libsymbolic_graph_jni.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mldv eng   154808 Aug  9 08:54 libutil.so
```

I always get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ~/myproduct/build/impl/libs/libsymbolic_graph_jni.so: libglog.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In other words, with -Djava.library.path set, my Java pp finds libsymbolic_graph_jni.so, but fails to find glog.so.0 on which that lib depend, *and which is in the same directory!*

What gives? I have all the shared libs in a dir, what do I need to do to have the Java classloader find them?

Comment: java.library.path looks like a Java property. So why do you assume that a setting there has an effect on the ldd tool which uses system paths to find native libraries?!

Comment: @GhostCat - I rephrased - I used ldd only to find the dependency. The problem is in my Java app which fails to find glog, although it finds libsymbolic_graph_jni.

Comment: how do you invoke/load libsymbolic_graph_jni.so in your java application, can paste that code here

Comment: If it can find the `libsymbolic_graph_jni.so`, then compiling it with the option `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'` (needs the quotes to prevent the `$ORIGIN` getting expanded by a shell), might help - it will cause the loader to search the directory that it finds `libsymbolic_graph_ini.so` when loading dependent libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your `java` app (assuming you are on Linux):

1) `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path-containing-so's>` (see [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

2) `java MainClass`

The -D property only affects where JVM looks for native libraries.